# Android Studio Project Structure Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

My AS0.5.3 Project structure dialog box misses many options. 
[image] What's causing this? Now I'm trying to add a global library and I couldn't.

**Update 1:**
  After updating my AS to 0.5.5 this is how my project structure looks :
    [image]

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio isn't the same as IntelliJ, and you don't tend to use global libraries the way you do there. Many libraries you need are available via the Maven Central repository, and you can have the build system download the correct version on the fly, instead of forcing you to maintain library jars by hand.

If you need to add a dependency to a common library, try the Modules > Dependencies > + button > Library dependency, and search for what you need.

If your dependency isn't on Maven Central, then you'll need to copy its jar archive into your project by hand. Android Studio doesn't presently have an equivalent to IntelliJ's global library feature.

Comment: The library im trying to use is not a common one. It is a downloaded 3rd party library

Comment: [This](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/26/developing-with-the-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-and-intellij-idea/)
 is the link I'm following. IS there any way I can do it?

Comment: I can do like this. But why is that my project structure is not complete? What's causing this problem. I havent seen much threads related to this problem. Is it because of anything I did during installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can add dependencies to files easily by
1- Copying the jar files to your project directory (put them in libs folder inside your project module)
2- open your project dependencies and choose to add "file dependency" 
3- locate the jar files and choose them

let me know if it is not working with you

Comment: I can do like this. But why is that my project structure is not complete? What's causing this problem. I havent seen much threads related to this problem. Is it because of anything I did during installation?